# Exporting CSV reports programmability using ServerReport.Render or ServerReport.RenderStream

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is there any to export reports to CSV programmability on SSRS 2008 R2 using ServerReport.Render or ServerReport.RenderStream??

It is weird because we can do it using Report Viewer, but I get some exceptions when change the format to CSV in code using the render.

Here is the code I am using that works perfectly exporting Reports in XLS, DOC and PDF formats:

```
        private void ExportReport(String format)
    {
        // Variables
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamIds;
        string mimeType = string.Empty;
        string encoding = string.Empty;
        string extension = string.Empty;

        string fileName = _reportName.Replace("Rep", "Report") + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm");

        PrepareReportParameters();
        rv.ServerReport.SetParameters(lstReportParameters);

        byte[] bytes = rv.ServerReport.Render(format, null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);

        // Now that you have all the bytes representing the PDF report, buffer it and send it to the client.
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = mimeType;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + "." + extension);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes); // create the file
        Response.Flush(); // send it to the client to download
    }
```

**Update 1**

Here is the exception I get when I select "CSV" as a "String formart" in the method above:

```
You have attempted to use a rendering extension that is either not registered for this report server or it is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services. (rsRenderingExtensionNotFound)
```

thanks

Comment: What are the "exceptions" you're getting? On a different note: did you consider using the SSRS Service API to do render reports? That seems way more convenient.

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen, I updated the question with the exception I get...No, did not consider to use that API because I did not know about it. I will take a look...

Comment: There is a report server config file that defines extensions. Can you verify that this extension is enabled on the server?